# Django how to update thousands of entries

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to optimize my application, basically what it's doing right now is filter/format/compute a JSON file and insert the data into my database.So I managed to optimize the create part by using `bulk_create`. But in most of the case I've to update instead of create, and I didn't find anything about a way to update many entries in same time instead of doing it one by one.

I tried to use `transaction.atomic` but not sure I use it properly.

```
with transaction.atomic():
    # Iterate trough all auctions from Json API 
    for a in auctionData.get('auctions') :
        # Check if item is in Item table
        if a.get('item') in itemsIdx :
            # Format data for database
            d = {k: v for k, v in a.items() if k in auctionFields}
            d['lastModified'] = apiLastModified
            auc = d.pop('auc', None)

            # if auction already in database update otherwhise create
            if auc in latestAuctionsIdx:
                currentEntry = Auction.objects.filter(auc=auc).update(**d)
            else :
                currentEntry = Auction(auc=auc, **d)
                currentEntry.save()
```

I still feel it's taking too much time, about 15sec for 3000 updates.
If you know anything to make it quicker, please let me know.
Cheers

Comment: Hi @MObject, You can try bulk update plugin. https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update, I don't say it is the best way but works, quick fix.

Comment: I will have a look, but I've read in other topics that is was mainly efficient for medium chunk size of update, but for large scale (thousands) it was not really good. Is it still the case ?